# InitializeComponent() does not exist - multi-targeted project (4.6.1 & 5)

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-5

I have a v4.6.1 class library project that contains some XAML functionality including some user controls. I've converted this project to .Net 5 then modified it to target both frameworks like so:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net5.0-windows;net461</TargetFrameworks>
```

The project *nearly* builds, apart from two XAML user controls that throw up the following error:

> The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

For some reason it's only affecting target framework "net461", but I'm struggling to solve this one. Any thoughts? It's not the usual suspects (BuildAction is "Page", same namespace in XAML and code-behind) as I see the problem when I add a new XAML user control to the project.

[image]

Comment: Is the .NET 4.6.1 development pack installed on your machine? Did you install it?

Comment: @thatguy I have both the SDK and targeting pack installed if that's what you mean?

Comment: I am observing the same issue. It is available for net5.0, but not for net4.8...

Comment: In my csproj first line was:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

after changing this to:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.SDK.WindowsDesktop">

I do not have this issue anymore...